# replace NLog in Azure

Tags: azure, nlog, graylog

We have a running site using NLog for logs. We are not only login errors, we use it to measure things relative to business logic.

Now we are moving to Azure and that's why I'm searching for a better way to log this type of info in azure. I'm looking for something like [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/).

Things to have in mind:

- What azure provides to log info is easy to read?
- Can i make queries to read data?
- Is there an API to log?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following stuff, which is more or less native to Azure. Also you could probably use some of the third parties, like New Relic.

- [Log Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/log-analytics/)
- [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/)
- [Operations Management Suite](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/insight-and-analytics)

> Application Insights not only has out of the box monitoring but also provides capabilities to create your own queries.

ps. Just my 2 cents, I'd go for OMS, Microsoft is pushing it oh so hard, it is evolving rapidly, even if you are missing some capabilities they are going to be there soon and in the long run, Microsoft is really unlikely to drop OMS anytime soon, since they started forcing it like 1.5 year ago.

Comment: Isn't OMS more for infrastructure monitoring instead?

When using Application Insights you can create your own queries over the data as well using analytics. Very, very powerful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics

Comment: so why are you copying a link from the post? anyway, with log analytics, you can analyze pretty much any logs.

Comment: It's different, an addition and zooms in to the analytics part. It shows that the question "Can i make queries to read data?" can be answered with that part.

Comment: whats different, my advice to use app insights is different from yours?

Comment: No. Let's not argue about the answer (I agree and upvoted) I just want to point out as an additional comment that Application Insights not only has out of the box monitoring but also provides capabilities to create your own queries. An easy to overlook feature. I meant that the link is different.

Comment: let me update that in my answer, to be honest log analytics also allows to query logs in your own custom ways, it also allows to create powerbi dashboard to enrich data visually